# Websocket only receives messages if Console.Write() is present, why is this?

Tags: c#, websocket, console-application

I am really having a headache with this weird "issue" with websockets, I am returning to programming from a pause of 10 years and I am learning websockets for the first time, so I must be doing something wrong.

I made a simple code in C# to open a websocket connection and receive messages (Book order updates) from Binance Websocket API, I followed their guidelines like sending a subscribe message in JSON format to be able to receive the messages.

And it works... BUT only if I put a `Console.Write("")` in the while loop below, if I don't it just stays in OPEN state and never exits the loop, standing there forever, the command `Console.WriteLine("after loop")` is never printed. I put this loop to wait the websocket to connect to the server (State from Connecting to Open).

If you see the code below, With the `Console.Write("")` commented the loop is never exited and the websocket messages are never received, uncomment it and everything will work fine.

I attached 2 images showing the output in Console, also tried to take out the "using" statement and put an infinite loop instead of `Console.ReadKey();`. But nothing seems to work, only if I uncomment the write command inside the loop, what I think it's bizarre...

Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

```
using SuperSocket.ClientEngine;
using System;
using WebSocket4Net;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/LOOMBTC@depth@100ms"))
            {
                websocket.Opened += new EventHandler(websocket_Opened);
                websocket.Error += new EventHandler<ErrorEventArgs>(websocket_Error);
                websocket.Closed += new EventHandler(websocket_Closed);
                websocket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(websocket_MessageReceived);
                websocket.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("before loop");
                while (websocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    //Console.Write("");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("after loop");
                websocket.Send("{\"method\": \"SUBSCRIBE\",\"params\":[\"loombtc@depth\"],\"id\": 1}");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static void websocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"socket OPENED, sender: {sender} and eventargs e: {e}");
        }

        private static void websocket_Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"socket ERROR, sender: {sender} and eventargs e: {e.Exception}");
        }

        private static void websocket_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"socket CLOSED, sender: {sender} and eventargs e: {e}");
        }

        private static void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"socket MESSAGE RECEIVED, sender: {sender} and eventargs e: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output with UNcommented Console.Write:

[image]

This is the output with commented Console.Write:

[image]

Comment: That loop is not needed. That’s what the opened callback is for.

Comment: Hi Johnny, I put that loop because I was getting an error about sending data before websocket was opened, like the output below, and also even when I take the loop out, the messages does not arrive, even when the "opened" messages appears: 

```before loop
after loop
socket ERROR, sender: WebSocket4Net.WebSocket and eventargs e: System.Exception: 
You must send data by websocket after websocket is opened!
socket OPENED, sender: WebSocket4Net.WebSocket and eventargs e: System.EventArgs:
```

Comment: @Returning you can move the `websocket.Send(...` to your `websocket_Opened` callback. `object sender` there should be the `WebSocket` itself, so you can just cast it like `... websocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e) => ((WebSocket) sender).Open(...`

Comment: @GuruStron ah ok, that's what Johnny was trying to tell me, I get it now, sorry too much time without programming I became slow hehe. But yes, it works now, perfectly. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this behavior only in `Release` mode and I would say that it seems to be compiler+JIT issue.

Here disassembly(can be viewed in VS Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly) code which is generated for non-loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("before loop");
00007FFA92B7223C  mov         rcx,2284EE030C8h  
00007FFA92B72246  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFA92B72249  call        00007FFA92B707C0  
00007FFA92B7224E  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-28h]  
00007FFA92B72252  cmp         dword ptr [rcx+0E0h],1  
00007FFA92B72259  je          00007FFA92B7227A  
                {
                    Console.Write("");
00007FFA92B7225B  mov         rcx,2284EE03060h  
00007FFA92B72265  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFA92B72268  call        00007FFA92B70868  
00007FFA92B7226D  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-28h]  
00007FFA92B72271  cmp         dword ptr [rcx+0E0h],1  
00007FFA92B72278  jne         00007FFA92B7225B  
                }
                Console.WriteLine("after loop");
```

And here is one with empty one:

```
                Console.WriteLine("before loop");
00007FFA92B5223C  mov         rcx,2BA99F630C8h  
00007FFA92B52246  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx]  
00007FFA92B52249  call        00007FFA92B507C0  
00007FFA92B5224E  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-28h]  
00007FFA92B52252  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rcx+0E0h]  
00007FFA92B52258  cmp         ecx,1  
00007FFA92B5225B  jne         00007FFA92B52258  
                {
                    //Console.Write("");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("after loop");
```

See the `00007FFA92B5225B jne 00007FFA92B52258` instruction ([jne](https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/jnz)) it points to `cmp` instruction which is **after** the `call` instruction(which should invoke getter of `websocket.State` property) and if we look at the similar instruction `00007FFA92B62278 jne 00007FFA92B6225B` in non-empty cycle version, then we will see that it points to `00007FFA92B6225B mov rcx,243DCA13060h` which is **before** the `call` one(and the state field is set asynchronously when the socket is ready).

TBH I don't know what to do next and who do you call now. Gostbusters? =)

**UPD.**

Played a little bit more. Would not claim that I understand the issue fully, but here is minimal repro:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new Container();
        c.SetNumber();

        Console.WriteLine("Before");
        while (c.NumberProp != 1)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("in");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Success!");


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Container
    {
        public void SetNumber()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                NumberProp = 1;
            });
        }

        public int NumberProp { get; set; }

    }
```

Submitted issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35762)

**LAST**(I hope) **UPD**

You have asked two questions: "Why is this? What am I doing wrong"

Lets start from the latter, as discussed in comments you should have moved the `Send` logic to your open callback like this:

```
    private static void websocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((WebSocket) sender).Send(....);
    }
```

As for the former, as correctly stated on Github (and me being sleepy and stupid during original analysis and totally forgetting about it) it is not a bug, it is "expected" unpredictable behavior, cause property(it's backing field) is changed in one thread and analyzed in other and the code can be subject to different optimizations(compiler, jitter and even in runtime by CPU depended on architecture). In my repro the issue can be fixed using [`volitile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) keyword like this:

```
    class Container
    {
        public void SetNumber()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                number_backing_field = 1;
            });
        }

        private volatile int number_backing_field;
        public int NumerProp => number_backing_field;
    }
```

If/when you will decide to dive deeper into the topic i recommend you watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wZVpg2SyJQ) great talk by Sasha Goldshtein.

Comment: Holly Molly... man I just got back to programming and already stumbled in a compiler bug, lucky me haha, thanks for the attention man, meanwhile I will use the solution you and Johnny gave me in the comments above. Peace.